# Filter a list based on some ComboBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a grid with data and above that grid 2 comboboxes, the grid will be filled with data based on the selected values from the comboboxes. This works but can you do it way easier like I did?

[image]

```
if (_InitialDataGridPersonList != null)
{
    if (GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText() == "-" && GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText() != "-")
    {
        var dataGridPersonQuery = _InitialDataGridPersonList
            .Where(w => w.Language.Equals(GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText()));

        foreach (var person in dataGridPersonQuery)
        {
            _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
        }
    }
    else if (GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText() != "-" && GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText() == "-")
    {
        var dataGridPersonQuery = _InitialDataGridPersonList
            .Where(w => (w.PersonState.Equals(GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText())));

        foreach (var person in dataGridPersonQuery)
        {
            _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
        }
    }
    else if (GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText() == "-" && GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText() == "-")
    {
        foreach (var person in _InitialDataGridPersonList)
        {
            _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
        }
    }
    else if (GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText() != "-" && GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText() != "-")
    {
        var dataGridPersonQuery = _InitialDataGridPersonList
            .Where(w => (w.PersonState.Equals(GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText()))
                    && (w.Language.Equals(GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText())));

        foreach (var person in dataGridPersonQuery)
        {
            _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
        }
    }
```

Imagine there are like 10 comboboxes. So what I'm asking is, if there is a easier way with less code?

PS. I'm using MVVM so no code behind.

Comment: If your comboboxes can grow fastly, [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/filter_pattern.htm) pattern can help you.

Comment: Of what type is `_DataGridPersonList`?

Comment: @Heslacher DataGridPerson

Comment: What I mean, is e.g `_DataGridPersonList` a `List<DataGridPerson` ?

Comment: Yes indeed. List<DataGridPerson>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a lot of code duplication. As a first step, your code should be rewritten somehow like that:

```
if (_InitialDataGridPersonList != null)
{
    var personState = GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText();
    var personLanguage = GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText();

    var personStateSpecified = personState != "-";
    var personLanguageSpecified = personLanguage != "-";

    if (!personStateSpecified && personLanguageSpecified)
    {
        AddPersons(_InitialDataGridPersonList
                   .Where(w => w.Language.Equals(personLanguage)));
    }
    else if (personStateSpecified && !personLanguageSpecified)
    {
        AddPersons(_InitialDataGridPersonList
                   .Where(w => w.PersonState.Equals(personState)));
    }
    else if (!personStateSpecified && !personLanguageSpecified)
    {
        AddPersons(_InitialDataGridPersonList);
    }
    else if (personStateSpecified && personLanguageSpecified)
    {
        AddPersons(_InitialDataGridPersonList
                   .Where(w => w.PersonState.Equals(personState) &&
                               w.Language.Equals(personLanguage)));
    }
}

private void AddPersons(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
    }
}
```

As a second step, you can place all comboboxes in a map where you'll link each combobox with property selector:

```
public enum PropertyType
{
    State,
    Language
}

private static readonly Dictionary<PropertyType, Func<Person, object>> _propertySelectors =
    new Dictionary<PropertyType, Func<Person, object>>
    {
        [PropertyType.State] = p => p.PersonState,
        [PropertyType.Language] = p => p.Language
    }

private void PopulatePersons()
{
    if (_InitialDataGridPersonList != null)
    {
        var propertyValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PropertyType))
                                 .Cast<PropertyType>()
                                 .ToDictionary(t => t,
                                               t => GetComboBoxText(t));

        AddPersons(_InitialDataGridPersonList.Where(p =>
        {
            return propertyValues.All(v => v.Value == "-" ||
                                           _propertySelectors[v.Key](p).Equals(v.Value)));
        });
    }
}

private void AddPersons(IEnumerable<Person> persons)
{
    foreach (var person in persons)
    {
        _DataGridPersonList.Add(person);
    }
}

private string GetComboBoxText(PropertyType propertyType)
{
    switch (propertyType)
    {
        case PropertyType.State:
            return GetSelectedComboBoxPersonStateText();
        case PropertyType.Language:
            return GetSelectedComboBoxPersonLanguageText();
        ...
    }

    return "-";
}
```

This approach allows you to add another comboboxes without a pain.

Comment: Hey, looks better but not working. Is there also a way to make the if else statements better or shorter?

Comment: @user7998549 _but not working_ and it doesn't have to ;-) It can be a suggestion. It's not required to present working code especially what so many unknowns as in our example

Comment: If you about first step there is nothing more there than you have provided in your original code. I've added second step which allows you to scale your app to more comboboxes.

Comment: @Maxim hmm nice thats works but only if I comment this part (the filter part :p) '_propertySelectors[v.Key](p).Equals(v.Value))));'

Comment: @user7998549 It is strange. Can you say, was your original code working? :) Because the code you've commented is necessary to select persons with properties values selected in comboboxes.

Comment: @Maxim yes if I comment '_propertySelectors[v.Key](p).Equals(v.Value))));' it returns all persons ofcours.

Comment: So what's wrong with `_propertySelectors[v.Key](p).Equals(v.Value)))`? Let's fix an issue together :)

Comment: the name 'Key' and the name 'Value'does not exist in the current context

Comment: I don't understand how it can be since the type of `propertyValues` is `Dictionary<PropertyName, string>` which means the type of its elements is `KeyValuePair<PropertyName, string>` and so it has `Key` and `Value`. Just checked this and all is OK with it.

Comment: Hmm yes it gives that error for me :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63670/discussion-between-maxim-and-user7998549).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to abstract your filters out. It does not require that much effort/extra code, yet it improves readability drastically.

```
interface IPersonFilter
{
    bool TryPass(Person person);
}

class StateFilter : IPersonFilter
{
    //You can implement INotifyPropertyChanged and bind combobox's 
    //Text or SelectedItem directly to this property, if you want to. 
    //That would simplify parent viewmodel. 
    public string State { get; set; }

    public bool TryPass(Person person)
    {
        if (State == "-") return true;
        return person.PersonState == State;
    }
}

//etc.
```

You can then construct your list as:

```
IPersonFilter[] allFilters = new IPersonFilter[] //this should be a property
{ 
    new StateFilter(), 
    new LanguageFilter() 
}; 
var filtered = _InitialDataGridPersonList.Where(p => allFilters.All(f => f.TryPass(p)));
_dataGridPersonList = new ObservableCollection<Person>(filtered);
```

P.S. In case you are not aware, wpf supports basic filtering out of the box. In order to use it you should create a `CollectionViewSource` and set its `Filter` delegate:

```
CollectionSource = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_InitialDataGridPersonList);
CollectionSource.Filter = p => 
{
    var person = (Person)p;

    //return true to display person, false - otherwise.

    //using above implementation:
    return allFilters.All(f => f.TryPass(p));
};
```

Then you can remove `_dataGridPersonList`, bind your grid to `CollectionSource` property instead and call `CollectionSource.DeferRefresh()` when filters change to update the view.